# How do I send a signal when my robot is within a given range of a goal?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to send my robot multiple goals (waypoints really) to pass through. Right now it stops at each goal that is sent. I thought of sending a new goal once it comes within range of the previous goal (assuming the sending of a new goal will mean it skips the old goal, as with sending 2D_nav_goal in Rviz).

This is my current code for sending two goals.

import time
import rospy
import actionlib
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
from std_msgs.msg import Int8

def movebase_client():
rate = rospy.Rate(1)

```
client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base',MoveBaseAction)
client.wait_for_server()

goal = MoveBaseGoal()
goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map"
goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 0.746
goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = 1.44
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 1

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = -0.9

client.send_goal(goal)
wait = client.wait_for_result()
if not wait:
    rospy.logerr("Action server not available!")
    rospy.signal_shutdown("Action server not available!")

#goal2
goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map"
goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 0.586
goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = 0.851
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 1

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = -0.9

client.send_goal(goal)
wait = client.wait_for_result()
if not wait:
    rospy.logerr("Action server not available!")
    rospy.signal_shutdown("Action server not available!")

else:
    return client.get_result()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
try:
rospy.init_node('movebase_client_py')
result = movebase_client()
if result:
rospy.loginfo("Goal execution done!")

```
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    rospy.loginfo("Navigation test finished.")
```

I imagine that I would monitor the amcl_pose topic and then use the location of the robot from that, but I dont know how to access the x, y, from the topic.

I'm using ROS melodic. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370763/how-do-i-send-a-signal-when-my-robot-is-within-a-given-range-of-a-goal?/) by [liambroek](https://answers.ros.org/users/68649/liambroek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get your robot position 2 different way.

1. Your robot transform to map (this is using generally for navigation - unlimited frequency)
2. amcl_pose (this is corrected with scan topic - low frequency)

If you need high frequency position data you need transform listener but specially if you need to you amcl_pose you can use at the bellow code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped,PoseStamped
def PoseCallBack(msg):
    data=""
    #Subscribed coordinate information
    x = msg.pose.pose.position.x
    y = msg.pose.pose.position.y
    #Subscribed quaternion information, used to indicate the direction
    orien_z = msg.pose.pose.orientation.z
    orien_w = msg.pose.pose.orientation.w

    data = str(x) + "," + str(y)+ "," + str(orien_z)+ "," + str(orien_w)
    rospy.loginfo(data)

def PoseSub():
    rospy.init_node('pose_sub',anonymous=False)
    #Monitor topics and handle them in the callback function
    rospy.Subscriber('/amcl_pose',PoseWithCovarianceStamped,PoseCallBack)
    rospy.spin()
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        PoseSub()
    except:
        rospy.loginfo("Error, exiting...")
```

---

Originally posted by [bekirbostanci](https://answers.ros.org/users/45026/bekirbostanci/) with karma: 76 on 2021-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1